# Save custom field in Keras model

Tags: python, keras

Consider the situation in which I have a trained Keras Sequential model. I save the model using

```
keras.saving.save_model(model, path, save_format="...")
```

Before saving, however, I set a custom `list[str]` attribute in the model this way:

```
setattr(model, "custom_attr", ["one", "two", "three"])
```

And finally, when I reload the model object (from another project) with `keras.saving.load_model`, I would like to have my custom attribute available via `model.custom_attr`. However, this doesn't work as custom_attr doesn't exist anymore after reloading the model.

**Is there any way to do that?**

I looked up a bit and it seems you can specify a `custom_objects` parameter when reloading the model, but that method seems to be limited to custom layers or custom loss functions defined in a custom model class. My setting is completely different as I have a normal `Sequential` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by subclassing the Sequential class and adding a parameter to the constructor:

```
class SequentialWithCustomAttr(keras.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, custom_attr=[], layers=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(layers=layers, trainable=kwargs["trainable"], name=kwargs["name"])
        self.custom_attr = custom_attr

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"custom_attr": self.custom_attr})

        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config, custom_objects=None):
        custom_attr = config.pop("custom_attr", None)

        # Deserialize layers one by one by using their configs.
        layers_confs = config.pop("layers", None)
        layers = list(map(keras.saving.deserialize_keras_object, layers_confs))

        # Create an instance of class SequentialWithCustomAttr.
        model = cls(custom_attr=custom_attr, layers=layers, **config)

        return model
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I guess is to save your custom attribute separately with the pickle module:

```
import pickle

# Your custom attribute
custom_attr = ["one", "two", "three"]

# Save the custom attribute to a file
with open("custom_attr.pkl", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(custom_attr, file)
```

After you reload the model, load this pickle as well and set your attributes `setattr(model, custom_attr)`

Comment: I considered a similar solution but, in my specific setting, it would be 10x more convenient if I could embed that attribute inside the model object.